# Put Two TextViews inside one chat bubble

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm building `MessageActivity` UI for my app and i want to put two TextView inside the chat bubble, that is the user name of the user and the message and i want the chat bubble to cover both TextView. But the chat bubble only expands with message length thereby messing up the view like this

[image: message ui]

so if the user name is long it will be outside the chat bubble

This is my layout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_message_body"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bubble_out"
    android:maxWidth="340dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="18dp"
    android:text="hi man, how are you?"
    android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_message_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:text="11:40"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/text_message_body"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/text_message_body" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/recieved_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:maxHeight="100dp"
    android:maxWidth="100dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grp_user_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:text="@string/display_name"
    android:textColor="#c9ce41"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/text_message_body"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/text_message_body" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting background only to your `text_message_body` remove it from there and set it to main parent container layout.

Comment: Yes, set the background to the main `ConstraintLayout` but also set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`, otherwise the whole width will have the bubble background.